# Get info from view that triggered onclick?

Tags: android, textview, gettext, settext

I'm completely new to Java and android. I ended a tutorial and I'm building a simple calculator to learn the ropes.

I basically have a view like this:

```
<button android:onClick="addText" android:text="2" />
```

And function addText is this:

```
public void addText(View view) { // Add view's text
    TextView calc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    t.setText( calc.getText() + ????? );
}
```

onclick it should add the text from the clicked button to a TextView. If you click 1, it does `calc.getText() + "1"` if you click 2 it `does calc.getText() + "2"`. I don't know how to get the clicked view's text. I tried this:   `t.setText( calc.getText() + this.getText() );` which didn't work. How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public void addText(View view) { // Add view's text
  Button button = (Button) view; //casts the View into the Button class
  TextView calc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
  t.setText(calc.getText().toString() + button.getText().toString());
}
```

Since we know that [`Button`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) is a subclass of [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html), and the `getText()` method works with buttons, we can make a new variable and turn the `View` parameter into a `Button`, via [class casting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html). From there we can use all the `Button`'s methods and continue with execution.

Comment: Thanks. I just implemented it. Could you add some comments next to the second line explaining it. I would like to know more of how this works. It's ok anyway.

Comment: @Liso22 I added some more info.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is by setting TAG object to your views

```
Button mButtonCalcOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
mButtonCalcOne.setTag(1);

OnClickListener mButtonListener = new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v )
    {
        int lButtonValue = (Integer) v.getTag();   //DO STH WITH IT ; )
    };
}
mButtonCalcOne.setOnClickListener( mButtonListener );
```